# Chaquopy cant find numpy, even though I installed it

Tags: python, android, pip, chaquopy

I want to use the library galois, which is an extension of numpy, in an android studio project with chaquopy. To download the libraries, I added

```
python{
    version "3.8"

    pip{
        install "cython"
        install "numpy==1.24.4"
        install "numba==0.6.0"
        install "galois"
    }
}
```

into my `build.gradle` file. However when I try to build the package I get this error:

```
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
     command: /usr/bin/python3 -S -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/tmp/pip-install-53dg7cfr/numba/setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'/tmp/pip-install-53dg7cfr/numba/setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' --no-user-cfg egg_info --egg-base pip-egg-info
         cwd: /tmp/pip-install-53dg7cfr/numba/
    Complete output (5 lines):
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
    ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:

      File "/tmp/pip-install-53dg7cfr/numba/setup.py", line 7, in <module>
        import numpy
    ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'numpy'
```

When I tried importing only numpy everything worked fine.

Answer (score 0):

For packages with native components such as NumPy and Numba, you can only install versions that are in [the Chaquopy repository](https://chaquo.com/pypi-7.0/). Either change your version numbers to one of the options from there, or remove them entirely to use the newest possible versions.

As for Cython, that's a build-time tool, not a runtime tool. Since you won't be building any packages, you should probably remove it from the list.

Comment: thanks, that worked, however i get this error when running the app `Caused by: com.chaquo.python.PyException: AttributeError: module 'numba.types' has no attribute 'FunctionType'`

Comment: Please create an issue on the [Chaquopy GitHub page](https://github.com/chaquo/chaquopy/issues), including the full stack trace and the relevant sections of your code.